# Not sure how to access array properly for comparing data?

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a function below.

The part that i cannot get to work is when checking `if $generatedkey == $key` in the `is_array` `if` statement.

It always goes straight to the `else` statement meaning the key did not match even thou in my sample array a key does match. I think I maybe not accessing the array properly in the `foreach` loop hence it never matches but not sure how to solve it. I did replace `return` with echo to test and always goes to `else` as stated above.

The test array in the code below will actually be results from a database which will be fetched as an array but for testing purposes I created a test array (`$userdbkey`).

```
# check if activation key already exists if so regenerate a new 
# one because activation keys are unique
function activationkeydupcheck($generatedkey, $userdbkey) {

    if(is_array($userdbkey)){
        foreach($userdbkey as $key){
            $key;
        }
        if($generatedkey == $key){
            while($generatedkey == $key){
               // generate a new key
               return $activationkeygenerator = activationkeygenerator();
            }
        } else {
            // else use original key as it's unique (ie not found in db)
            return $activationkeygenerator = $generatedkey;
        }

    } else { // not an array
        if($generatedkey == $userdbkey){
            while($generatedkey == $userdbkey){
            // generate a new key
            return $activationkeygenerator = activationkeygenerator();
            }
        } // else use the original as it's unique (ie not found in db)
        return $activationkeygenerator = $generatedkey;
    }
}
// for testing it's static, but in my script it will be auto generated by a a function that generates activation keys.
$generatedkey     =   'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv1';
//$userdbkey      =   'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv1';

// for testing i made this test array but in my script it will be comparing against keys in a database which will be fetched as an array.
$userdbkey        = array(
                    'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv1',
                    'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv2',
                    'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv3',
                    'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv4',
                    'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv5',
                    'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv6',
                    'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv7',
                    'g5kfjgh84hf5jk219fthjvmcd34tu79ldjhgnbmv8',                  
                    );

activationkeydupcheck($generatedkey, $userdbkey);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the foreach & while loops. Just use php functions and tenary operator to simplify your function:

```php
function activationkeydupcheck($generatedkey, $userdbkey) {
  if(is_array($userdbkey)){
    return in_array($generatedkey, $userdbkey) ? activationkeydupcheck(activationkeygenerator(), $userdbkey) : $generatedkey;
  } else { // not an array
    return $generatedkey == $userdbkey ? activationkeydupcheck(activationkeygenerator(), $userdbkey) : $generatedkey;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rob i thought i needed the while loop because if $generatedkey kept generating keys that already existed i would want it to continue generating one until a unique one is found? thanks

Comment: if you wish to reply in regards to the while loop, on further looking i think your maybe the best answer now, so if you could reply about above i'd appreciate it, as think i may now have accepted wrong answer. Thank you. Would i need to call for the function actionkeydupcheck() in a while loop when checking if generated key already exists or just call the function?

Comment: because i need it to keep generating a new key until a unique one is found hence my question about needing while loop. Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer so that activationkeygenerator() is called until it returns a unique key...

Comment: Both Rob and Matt provided solutions and i originally accepted Matt's answer as the solution as he provided allot of information & explanations, however since looking more carefully at Rob's solution, Rob's solution is more cleaner, simpler to use & does not require a while loop when calling the activationkeydupcheck() as i need activationkeygenerator() to keep regenerating a key until it generates a unique one that does not match what's already in the database. Essentially it's cleaner code with simpler integration and is exceptionally less code and much better than my own...

Comment: ... therefore now accepting Rob's answer as the solution. Thank you both though as both Rob and Matt offered good solutions in different ways. Many thanks to Rob and Matt.

Answer (score 1):

Look how foreach is working. 
Should be :

```
 foreach($userdbkey as $key){
        $key;    // u are doing nothing here        
    if($generatedkey == $key){
        while($generatedkey == $key){               
           return $activationkeygenerator = activationkeygenerator();
        }
    } else {
        return $activationkeygenerator = $generatedkey;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Many thanks @Matt, I can now see what i did wrong and it's so silly of me to not notice the mistake and although i went on w3schools to understand foreach loop i still got it wrong, thank you very much for your help. All works good now.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `if(is_array($userdbkey)){` is correct for checking for an array.  If it's not evaluating true, try doing `print_r($userdbkey)` and `exit` to see what's going on, because I see nothing wrong with that.

As for your function code, here is a cleaned up version with comments. I changed it so that it will return `true` if a duplicate is found and `false` otherwise, since you are trying to force a unique id.

```
function activationkeydupcheck($generatedkey, $userdbkey) {
    if(is_array($userdbkey)){
        foreach($userdbkey as $key){
            if($generatedkey == $key){
                // Found duplicate
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else { // not an array
        if($generatedkey == $userdbkey){
            // Found duplicate
            return true;
        }
    }

    // No duplicates
    return false;
}
```

And then you can invoke it like so:

```
// While this is true (duplicates are found), change the key
while( activationkeydupcheck($generatedkey, $userdbkey) ) {
    $generatedkey = activationkeygenerator();
}
```

In your original code, the statement `while($generatedkey == $key)` will loop forever because `$generatedkey` never changes inside the loop. But instead, you just return a new key which stops execution immediately on the first loop.  So your duplicate checker would return the new key, and keep on going not checking that one.

And if you like less lines that do just as much, just force the `$userdbkey` to always be an array:

```
function activationkeydupcheck($generatedkey, $userdbkey) {
    // If this isn't an array, make it one
    if(!is_array($userdbkey)) {
        // Same as $userdbkey = array($userdbkey)
        $userdbkey = [$userdbkey];
    }

    return in_array($generatedkey, $userdbkey);
}
```

Just like the other one, this returns true if a duplicate is found in `$userdbkey` and false if not.  It can be invoked the same way.

Comment: Hi @CaptainHypertext i thought i needed the while loop still because if $generatedkey kept generating keys that already existed i would want it to continue generating one until a unique one is found?

Comment: many thanks, i am accepting your answer because not only you replied back to comment but you provided a good clear solution with good explanations and explaining why i didn't need the while loop, your codes has also assisted me in terms of improving parts of my other code so this is why i'm accepting your as the answer and solution. Many thanks for all your help. It was much appreciated. Have a nice day!

Comment: @PHPLOVER Glad I could help!